# Posting a review to ReviewBoard using git diff

Tags: git, diff, review-board

I am trying to post a review to RB using git diff with the following command:

```
$ git diff --full-index cce8e84aa2d268d04271737c09dd550d2ca8318b..ebd06031e088e
4f9e0fbc938258d152e3d7deced > test_patch.txt
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
The file 'PolicyCenter/modules/configuration/config/web/pcf/line/cp/policy/CPBuildingsAndLocationsLV.pcf' (r92eef9030169b4629c4a457ee0f555a3f69a1bf1) could not be found in the repository
```

I have read that RB cannot handle commit SHAs but couldn't find an alternative way of creating the diff.

Any ideas?

Comment: why dont't you use `post-review` ?

Comment: I think I would need Python installed to use the command line utilities and that's something I would like to avoid.